# Why nvidia-smi displays only 127MB memory out of 512MB available?

Tags: nvidia, memory

I Have a GeForce 210 and i use the Nvidia-current driver. I know my card has 512MB but that command shows differently. I also noticed that after upgrading  from 11.04 my graphics' performance got worse. It feels like the system doesn't use 512MB anymore, but 127MB instead.
Nvidia-setting, though, shows 512MB available .

I use 12.04, fully updated.

What do you guys think about this?

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 3.295.40   Driver Version: 295.40         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Nb.  Name                     | Bus Id        Disp.  | Volatile ECC SB / DB |
| Fan   Temp   Power Usage /Cap | Memory Usage         | GPU Util. Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0.  GeForce 210               | 0000:02:00.0  N/A    |       N/A        N/A |
|  N/A   42 C  N/A   N/A /  N/A |  64%   81MB /  127MB |  N/A      Default    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------|
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU  PID     Process name                                       Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  0.           Not Supported                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: There is some graphics cards (GC) that use partly the RAM memory available. --Example: You GC have 256Mb, your RAM 1Gb, then your GC use 256 more from the RAM and now: GC 512Mb, Ram 768Mb.-- I think that it's your case.

Comment: Well i have 2GB of ram. And GC specs say it has 512MB. So i have plenty of ram. It shouldn't show/use only 127MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nvidia-smi and nvidia-settings tools report memory in different ways.  For nvidia-settings the total reported memory includes the system memory that the GPU can use, as Lucio mentions.  For nvidia-smi only memory on the GPU is reported.  Both of these tools are working as expected.